# Rails POST with cross-domain XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, xmlhttprequest

I've got a Rails v4.0.2 application setup and hosted on Heroku. I've temporarily disabled the CSRF Authenticity Token checking to allow POST of JSON data from an outside source. When I do a POST using the Advanced REST Client extension in Chrome, it works fine and creates the new record. However, when trying to create the exact same POST in JavaScript with an ajax call, I'm receiving the following errors:

OPTIONS http://herokudomain.com/users.json 404 (Not Found)

OPTIONS http://herokudomain.com/users.json No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://requestdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://herokudomain.com/users.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://requestdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I particularly don't understand the 404 error, as I'm certainly using the right URL, though I've changed it here for demonstration purposes. If I copy the URL from the error message and past into my browser, I'm taken to the desired page, not a 404.

Can someone please help enlighten me on what the difference is in using the Advanced REST Client and using an XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript, and how I can work around this issue?

EDITS:

Here is the code for my test page, which I've tried running via localhost and on a hosted domain: http://pastebin.com/z3hJEX8c

Answer (score 1):

add these lines in your application controller it will allow cross domain requests but for security you can define your domain

```
before_filter :allow_ajax_request_from_other_domains

 def allow_ajax_request_from_other_domains
   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
   headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
 end
```

Comment: I already had something like this, except for the last line, 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'. I've added it and still continue to get the same error. I should have specified that I'm using Rails v4.0.2, as the other questions I've looked at on Stack Overflow seem to indicate different solutions for varying versions of Rails.

Comment: It's working on rails 3.2 but I didn't tried it on rails4 I was facing that problem for 1 week also I think the problem will be too on CRFS tokens ,try to uncomment protect_from_forgery in your application controller if it's work I will provide you with the code to make it working

Comment: I have already commented the protect_from_forgery line out of the application controller, this is what allowed it to work using Advanced REST Client extension in Chrome. For some reason it behaves differently when using Javascript and I am still receiving these errors.

Comment: Would you mind writing your js code so i can test it

Comment: I posted my entire test page here: http://pastebin.com/z3hJEX8c This includes all the HTML with JS on a single page.

Comment: on your code remove req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
  req.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");

Comment: I removed those lines and I'm no longer receiving the 404 error, but still get the error about allowing access control headers: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://herokudomain.com/users.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://requestdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do that? I'm not having any success trying to Google "XMLHttpRequest datatype json".